# How to get mouse click position in qml Image component?

Tags: image, qml

I tried to get the mouse click position in qml Image component, but what I got is not the real pixel-based image position, how can I get the pixel-based position of the image?

this is my qml code

```
Image {
    id: sourceImage
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: "D://test.png"
    mipmap: true
    smooth: true
    antialiasing: true

    MouseArea {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        focus: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            print("clicked:", mouse.x,mouse.y)
        }
    }

}
```

the real image size is 3840*1260, but when I click the bottom-right position with the mouse, it prints clicked: 683 547

Comment: Because your `Image` has `width: parent.width` and `height: parent.height` and `fillMode: Image.PreservedAspectFit` from the numbers you supplied, we know that your image is scaled. If you know the real image size, you can undo the scaling by multiplying mouse.x and mouse.y by the scale factor.

Comment: the purpose of using fillMode: Image.PreservedAspectFit  is showing image in its parent's center. Undo the scaling by multiplying mouse.x and mouse.y is accurate? Maybe the best way to get the real position in image is showing image in the origin size, but another problem occurs: how can i show image of origin size in the center of its parent component ?

Comment: You need to approximate the scale calculation done by the `Image.PreservedAspectFit` something like `property double scale: Math.min(3840/width, 1260/height)` ? Once you figured it out. That's your multiplication factor. You should be able to troubleshoot on your own. The math is no more harder than that. If there's offset / clipping involved. You should think about working out this scale factor first. Then, position your `MouseArea` accordingly to reduce the need to add/subtract an offset.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the code is boilerplate for debugging. The important part is the three functions `mapToImage()` and `getXPosition()`/`getYPosition()`. The latter is for getting the offset at which the image is drawn, when `Image.PreservedAspectFit` can't fill the `Image` and `horizontalAlginment`/`verticalAlignment` are used.

The map function uses `sourceSize` and `paintedWidth`/`paintedHeight` to get the scaling between the original size of the image and the actual drawn image. Keep in mind that when changing `sourceSize` and not letting the image set it, this method of getting the scaling might not work.

Just a note from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop):

> sourceSize can be cleared to the natural size of the image by setting
> sourceSize to undefined.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Image Picking")

    function getXPosition(image : Image) : real {
        switch (image.horizontalAlignment) {
            case Image.AlignLeft:
                return 0
            case Image.AlignRight:
                return image.width - image.paintedWidth
            case Image.AlignHCenter:
            default:
                return (image.width - image.paintedWidth) * 0.5
        }
    }

    function getYPosition(image : Image) : real {
        switch (image.verticalAlignment) {
            case Image.AlignTop:
                return 0
            case Image.AlignBottom:
                return image.height - image.paintedHeight
            case Image.AlignVCenter:
            default:
                return (image.height - image.paintedHeight) * 0.5
        }
    }

    function mapToImage(mouse : MouseEvent, image : Image) {
        root.xScale = image.paintedWidth / image.sourceSize.width
        root.yScale = image.paintedHeight / image.sourceSize.height

        root.xImgPosition = Math.floor((mouse.x - root.getXPosition(image)) / root.xScale)
        root.yImgPosition = Math.floor((mouse.y - root.getYPosition(image)) / root.yScale)
    }

    property real xScale: 0
    property real yScale: 0
    property real xImgPosition: 0
    property real yImgPosition: 0

    Image {
        id: image
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 320
        height: 240
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        //horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignLeft
        source: "https://picsum.photos/id/17/200/300"
        mipmap: true
        smooth: true
        antialiasing: true

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onPositionChanged: function(mouse) { root.mapToImage(mouse, image) }
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            border {
                width: 1
                color: "gray"
            }
        }

        // Debug rectangle showing the real dimension of the image before clipping by the fillMode
        Rectangle {
            x: root.getXPosition(image)
            y: root.getYPosition(image)
            width: image.paintedWidth
            height: image.paintedHeight
            color: "transparent"
            border {
                width: 1
                color: "red"
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: column.width + 40
        height: column.height + 40
        color: Qt.rgba(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4)

        Column {
            id: column
            x: 20
            y: 20
            spacing: 4

            ComboBox {
                width: 180
                textRole: "text"
                valueRole: "value"
                onActivated: image.fillMode = currentValue
                Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = indexOfValue(image.fillMode)
                model: [
                    { value: Image.Stretch, text: qsTr("Stretch") },
                    { value: Image.PreserveAspectFit, text: qsTr("Preserve Aspect Fit") },
                    { value: Image.PreserveAspectCrop, text: qsTr("Preserve Aspect Crop") }
                ]
            }

            Text { text: "Mouse:    " + mouseArea.mouseX + ", " + mouseArea.mouseY }
            Text { text: "Image:    " + image.width + ", " + image.height }
            Text { text: "Painted:  " + image.paintedWidth + ", " + image.paintedHeight }
            Text { text: "Source:   " + image.sourceSize.width + ", " + image.sourceSize.height }
            Text { text: "Scaling:  " + root.xScale + ", " + root.yScale }
            Text { text: "Position: " + root.xImgPosition + ", " + root.yImgPosition }
        }
    }
}
```